# Windows XP on VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I've been trying to install Windows XP onto my computer using virtualbox, but it keeps giving me this: [image]

So how do I fix this, it just isn't installing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a vm for WinXP and it attached the hdd as IDE, on your image is attached as SATA.

Answer (score 0):

just unmount the iso you used. The problem is the virtual box boots from the iso file you added not from the virtual harddisk